# Reload Screen flow after record edit

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, visual-workflow, screen-flow

I've created a screen flow which is placed on the record page and shows description based on values from picklist field.
Eevery time I change the values, the screen flow keeps showing the old description and doesn't update.
Only when I refresh the whole page, the flow shows the correct description.

Is there a way to force the screen flow to be refreshed when values are updated on the record?

Would someone be able to provide an example of how I can accomplish this?

Thanks !

Comment: Reactive updates within screen flow screens are [on the way](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2023/flow-reactive-screen-components-beta-learn-moar-summer-23), if that is what you mean...

Comment: What's your budget?